# Vue Prop undefined for just the first item in v-for loop using a component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a component that looks like this.

```
#this is the <review-stars> component
export default {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    props: ['NumStars', 'RecipeName'],                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

    data() {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        return{                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
            stars: this.NumStars,                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
            recipe: this.RecipeName,                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
        }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    },                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

    mounted () {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    },                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
}
```

It has a  section as well, but things are find there.

I then have my html page that looks like this.

```
<recipe-selects inline-template>                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
<div>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        <table class='table table-striped'>                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
            <thead>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
            </thead>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
            <tbody>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          

                <tr v-for="(item, index) in recipes" :key="index">                                                                                                                                                                                           

                    <td class=""><a v-bind:href="'/recipe/'+item.id+'/view'" v-text="item.title"></a></td>                                                                                                                                                   
                    <td>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

                    @{{item.overall_star}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
                    <review-stars :num-stars="item.overall_star" :recipe-name="item.title" >                                                                                                                                                                 
                    </review-stars>                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
                    </td>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
                </tr>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
            </tbody>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
        </table>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             

</div>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
</recipe-selects>
```

I have a component attached to  and that works fine.  It is an ajax call that loads the data for the v-for and I get a listing of recipes back.  It is an inline component.

But, then I have another component that attaches to  where I try to bind some props and pass them to my component I showed above.

When the v-for loop runs, I get a list of all the recipes.  I also get a list of the 'review-stars' appropriately.

EXCEPT for the very first item in the for loop.

Here is Vue Dev tools showing the first created ReviewStars instances shows data as undefined.  [image]
But in this you see that the second (and any further rows, but I limited it here to just 2 results) work exactly as expected.[image]

Both show that the actual props get defined and picked up.  But the props are only passed to the data (stars and recipe) from the second v-for loop and onwards.

What am I missing to assign the data (stars and recipe) in the FIRST v-for loop?

Comment: Are NumStars and RecipeName simple arrays? (Might you need to write: ```stars: this.NumStars.data```?)

Comment: @nbixler Yeah they are just json objects from laravel.  When I try adding .data I get the same behavior.  First v-for is undefined, 2nd onwards have the props correctly added to the data variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `props` are not there yet to populate the values in `data`. You have to wait for the `created` hook for everything to be ready and then you can use the values from `props`. You can use them directly from `props`. The only reason to duplicate them in `data` is if they are modified in this component.

```
export default {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    props: ['NumStars', 'RecipeName'],                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    data() {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        return{                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
            stars: null,                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
            recipe: null,                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
        }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    },
    created () {
        this.stars = this.NumStars   
        this.recipe = this.RecipeName
    },                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
}
```